# How to use ActionBar features from a fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

In a fragment code I'd like to make ActionBar API calls such as

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

Is it a good idea to hold a reference to the activity in the fragment's code or is there a better way to approach this?

I'm using SherlockFragment for compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized SherlockFragment has `getActivity()` and `getSherlockActivity()` methods, so I can write:

```
this.getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
this.getSherlockActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Comment: @Kogan Where this code will be placed in ListFragment